# Does V8 have an event loop?

Tags: v8, event-loop

I keep hearing V8 has its rudimentary event loop implementation but

1. couldn't find it
2. doesn't really make sense to me. Methinks, the simplest design of a JS engine would be to simply run synchronously and let the "embedder" write their own event loop - like nodejs got libuv.

Is there an event loop implementation in v8? If so, could you point me at it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your intuition is right that the event loop is something that embedders should have control over. However, it is also a fundamental abstract concept of the JavaScript programming model. V8's solution is to provide a default implementation that embedders can override; you can find it in the "libplatform" component: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/libplatform/default-platform.cc#140

See also [Relationship between event loop,libuv and v8 engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811043/relationship-between-event-loop-libuv-and-v8-engine)

Comment: As a javascript beginner, I have a doubt, does the event loop and javascript code is running in the same thread?

Comment: Effectively yes. The "event loop" isn't really a thing that's running; it's mostly just a queue of callbacks waiting for their turn to run.

Comment: @jmrk `event loop` is a queue of callbacks, it makes sense to me. could you suggest a resource where i can get proper understanding of `event loop`?

Comment: Maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop ?